# background image wont show in most recent version of ie

Tags: css

```
body {
   background-position: right;
   color: #FF7F27;
   background-color: transparent; 
   background-image url('../cityage_background3.png');
   background-size: 1386px 861px;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

The link is just n example. i know the real link works because it show up in cchrome and firefox. Why isnt the background image showing up in internet explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is here:

```
background-image url('../cityage_background3.png');
```

It should be:

```
background-image: url('../cityage_background3.png');
```

You were missing :

Edit*  IE does not like errors.

Answer (score 1):

you forget your **:** between background-image and url

Answer (score 0):

if it doesn't work, it's because your path is not correct. Make sure your image is in the right place.

Comment: the path is correct i checked it. the problem is caused by code being loaded before the doctype.